# jQuery UI 1.10.1 Tooltip not showing unless tracking is enabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I am stuck trying to get jQuery tooltips to appear. They only show when tracking is enabled.

```
$('.tooltip[title]').tooltip({track:true});
```

That works just fine, and the tooltips appear moving with the mouse cursor.

```
$('.tooltip[title]').tooltip();
```

Does not work as expected.

When inspecting the elements with the `tooltip` class. I can see that jQuery is creating the tooltip, because the attribute `aria-describedby` is added to the element, and removed when the cursor leaves the element. So it appears that the tooltip element is being created, but I don't see it anywhere on the screen.

I have tried adding the following to my CSS files.

```
.ui-tooltip {
     position: absolute !important;
     z-order: 999999 !important;
}
```

But that makes no different, and the tooltip shows just fine when tracking is enabled so I doubt it's my CSS.

I've also tried multiple combinations of different `position` settings, and tried all the `position/collision` settings, but nothing works.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to specify [title] like that.  Just do `$('.tooltip').tooltop();` and put the `title='my tooltip'` in your element.

Comment: @user1477388 removing it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Did you also trying removing your CSS?  If that doesn't work, post your HTML so I can see what the problem is.  A failsafe:  `$(document).tooltip();`.